# how to disconnect clients in BluetoothGattServer side

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I got an Android app that play server role and an iOS app that play client role.

And now, I want to break their connection(unpair is better).

I have tried CBCentralManager.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral) method in swift.It doesn't work since you have used ANCS. According to [document](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1518952-cancelperipheralconnection), I can't disconnect physical link, even I got a disconnect callback in code.I suppose I used ANCS.That's why I can't disconnect physical link.

Then, I try to break the connection in server side(Android).However, it doesn't work, even I call BluetoothGattServer.cancelConnection(BluetoothDevice), BluetoothDevice.removeBond() and BluetoothGattServer.close(), because client(iOS) will auto reconnect server.

Thus, my question is
How can I disconnect central device when I am playing peripheral role on iOS in swift(or Objective-C)
or
How can I disconnect client(iOS) when I am playing server(gattServer) on Android

Comment: It is up to the central to initiate connections and end connections. iOS will not reconnect unless your Android app is trying to connect.  On the iOS side you can `remove` your service from the `CBPeripheralManager` but this won't affect the ANCS service which is published by iOS

Comment: from iOS side, I didn't add services to CBPeripheralManager. And I don't know how to use CBPeripheralManager to disconnect my Android app. I try to unpair iOS app in my Android app, but iPhone will try to repair my Android phone.And bluetooth of my Android phone have no password or any confirmation, thus, iPhone will reconnect my Android phone in BLE channel.

Comment: You shouldn't unpair.  I don't know anything about Bluetooth on Android but on iOS if you call `cancelConnection` it will disconnect. According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Specification/Specification.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013460-CH1-SW19) you need to unsubscribe from the notification source characteristic.

Comment: I have tried `cancelConnection`, and I also go to `didDisconnect` callback in my swift code.However, when I go to system setting, I saw the device is still connected that means I can't disconnect remote device in physical. What I want is to disconnect my Android phone in physical. Besides, how should I unsubscribe ANCS?

Comment: All you need to worry about is if your app is disconnected/no longer receiving notifications. What does it matter if the device is showing as connected in settings?  As far as unsubscribing goes, I assume you are setting `notify` on the notification source characteristic in order to get the notifications from iOS

Comment: yeah, my Android phone(peripheral) have the same service and characteristics in ANCS. And I set the characteristics to notify. The service is for Android. It make me can receive notifications from another Android phone. So, should I remove the service in my peripheral?